# Create control from XAML in codebehind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, code-behind

I have XAML defining something, say:

```
<Path Data="M16.25,11 L0.5,0.5 L32,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="11" Margin="1.542,0.25,18.458,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Can I do something like this in codebehind:

```
Path myPath = Path.FromXAML("
    <Path Data="M16.25,11 L0.5,0.5 L32,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="11" Margin="1.542,0.25,18.458,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>");
```

Obviously with appropriate escape characters to ensure the string parses properly.

I recall that this was possible but I can't remember the specifics..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, using XamlReader.Load does it nicely.

One small modification I have to make to the code is add the namespace, so to convert this:

```
<Path Data="M16.25,11 L0.5,0.5 L32,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="11" Margin="1.542,0.25,18.458,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

To run via XamlReader.Load I do:

```
Path p = XamlReader.Load(<Path **xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"**  Data="M16.25,11 L0.5,0.5 L32,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="11" Margin="1.542,0.25,18.458,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>);
```

(obviously would also have to add escape characters for quotation marks)